# How to fix or replace this part of my sink faucets?

Tags: plumbing, sink, plumbing-fixture

I have a faucet that is made of some nice metal that I'd rather repair than replace:

[image: Faucet]

The cartridge in both handles that seems to me to be broken:

[image]
[image]

When the water supply is turned on, water slowly leaks out from the very top of both of the cartridges, right where the handles connect to them -- right at the blue line drawn on this photo:

[image]

I took the cartridge apart to see if I could see anything broken or deteriorated, but it all looked fine to me:

[image]

Not seeing any other solution, I replaced the two rubber O-rings inside the cartridges, but it did not fix the problem.

I am open to any solution which ends with this faucet and handles not leaking.  I can imagine two solutions, and if there's another one I didn't think of that works, great!

1. A way to fix / install the cartridges so they don't leak.
2. The model number for the cartridges (or the entire faucet unit) so I can try to find replacement pieces for purchase.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are faucet cartridges that eventually wear out, start leaking, and need to be replaced. Most cartridges are readily available either online or at your **local plumbing store**. You might even be able to find the correct one at your home goods store.
I would suggest that you start by identifying the brand of faucet you have. It should be imprinted somewhere on the faucet itself. Once you know the brand you can call the manufacturers 800 number and talk with their customer service folks. It's helpful to have a model # but in many instances they can identify it from a picture of the faucet or the part. They are usually extremely helpful in helping you identify the part you will need. I have had great experiences with several who shipped me the part at no charge.
It all just takes some patience and a little research.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no brand name written anywhere on the faucet.

Comment: It sort of looks like this one on amazon, but is different: https://www.amazon.com/Votamuta-Mounted-Widespread-Bathroom-Finished/dp/B01H6B0S1G

Comment: Your best bet is to take the cartridges to a plumbing store - not a big box store. A plumbing store may be able to match up the cartridges.